# Why my presentModalViewController method doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I created a UIImagePickerController in the viewDidLoad method in my rootViewController.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImagePickerController *pickerController=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    pickerController.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    pickerController.delegate=self;

    [self presentModalViewController:pickerController animated:YES];
    [pickerController release];
}
```

But the view of UIImagePickerViewController didn't appear on the screen.

The SDK version is 4.3

Is there some mistakes i make?

Thanks!

Comment: wouldn't it work every time the view appears?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is called after the view has been loaded and before the view is displayed. `viewDidAppear:` is called when the view is onscreen and is the correct point to present a modal view controller.

And if you want to do it only once, you might want to consider using a `BOOL` to keep track of it.